# The sum of $2012$ positive terms is $10.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A sequence has $2012$ positive terms adding to $10$
Prove that the sum of product of two consecutive terms is less than $25.$

I've tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but couldn't find the proof.

Also find the maximum value (where equality holds).

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean "Show that $\sum_{i = 1}^{2012}a_i = 10$ and $a_i \geq 0$ implies $\sum_{i = 1}^{2011}a_i\cdot a_{i+1} \leq 25$"?

Comment: @Arthur Yes you got the question right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{2012}$ be the sequence at hand.
Notice in the sum of consecutive terms

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1}$$
One factor comes from the set $\{ a_1, a_3, a_5, \cdots a_{2011} \}$ while the other one comes from the set $\{ a_2, a_4, \cdots, a_{2012} \}$. Furthermore,
not every pair of $a_i a_j$ with $i$ odd, $j$ even are included in the sum.

This leads to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1} < \left(\sum_{i\text{ odd}} a_i\right) \left(\sum_{j\text{ even}} a_j\right)
\le \left(\frac{\sum_{i\text{ odd}} a_i + \sum_{j\text{ even}} a_j}{2}\right)^2
= \left(\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{2012} a_i\right)^2 = 25\tag{*1}$$

About the other question concerning the maximum value, the maximum value doesn't exist.

For any small $\epsilon$, if we set $a_1 = a_2 = 5-1005\epsilon$ and $a_k = \epsilon$ for $k > 2$, we have

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2012} a_k = 10
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1} = (5-1005\epsilon)^2 + (5-1005\epsilon)\epsilon + 2009 \epsilon^2
$$

This implies
$$S \stackrel{def}{=} \sup \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1} \right\} \ge \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}
(5-1005\epsilon)^2 + (5-1005\epsilon)\epsilon + 2009 \epsilon^2 = 25$$

Since $(*1)$ implies $S \le 25$, the supremum of the sum $S = 25$.

Notice the inequality in $(*1)$ is always strict. There are no configuration of $a_k$ which can make the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1}$ equal to the supremum. This means the maximum doesn't exist.

Comment: Where are the other answers?

Comment: Can we somehow find its maximum value?

Comment: @user481779 the maximum value doesn't exist. If you set $a_1 = a_2 = 5-1005\epsilon$ and the rest $a_k = \epsilon$. $\sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_k a_{k+1}$ can be as close as $25$ but never reach that. i.e. $\sup \{ \sum_{k=1}^{2011} a_ka_{k+1} \} = 25$.